# Evil: how to execute multiple commands at command line?

Tags: evil

I want to execute a list of commands all at once in the evil's command line. In vim, you can use the pipe to execute multiple commands, like this:

```
%s/ó/o/g|%s/ç/c/g
```

How can I do this in evil?